# How can I download music files from websites using #Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

1. How can I download music files from websites using #Python

**this code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import *
import urllib

link = input("https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/")

url = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
for audio in soup.find_all('audio'):
    print(len(audio))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Downloads files from url using python .py", line 8, in <module>
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 501, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 320, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 346, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 375, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: ''
```

> I want through the website link to extract the links mp3 and wav
> Please someone who can help me

Comment: first of don't import everything (don't use `*` when importing), second what do you think this line does: `link = input("https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/")`? it asks for input and what you input is referenced by `link` so you either enter the url in the console or simply do `link = "https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/"`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use next example how to download all `mp3` files from that page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

url = "https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for u in soup.select("[data-url]"):
    u = u["data-url"]
    print("Downloading {}".format(u))
    with open(u.split("/")[-1], "wb") as f_out:
        f_out.write(requests.get(u, headers=headers).content)
```

Prints:

```
Downloading https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/John_Bartmann_-_09_-_Happy_Clappy-1.mp3
Downloading https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/batchbug-sweet-dreams.mp3
Downloading https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/fm-freemusic-inspiring-optimistic-upbeat-energetic-guitar-rhythm.mp3
Downloading https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/keys-of-moon-white-petals.mp3


...and so on.
```

and saves the `*mp3` files.

Comment: btw are `headers` necessary?

Comment: it's working thank you broooo But I didn't understand this

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

Comment: @Matiiss Without the last `headers=` the server sent null response.

Comment: @sakomalten Sometimes to get correct response from server you need to set correct HTTP headers. In this case I've received null response from the server when I tried to download the mp3s

Comment: @Matiiss yes it's necessary